# Why can't I put children in my Falkreath house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I got my Falkreath house, but it says I own no homes in my game stats. Also, I can't adopt a child. Do I need both child's beds and chest before I can adopt one? What's up with this?

Comment: Do you have child beds and child containers? Because that's what they need right?